# Generate a list of functions with and without arguments to be executed inside a loop to not repeat lines with SpreadsheetApp.flush()

Tags: google-apps-script

My original code:

```
    funct_a(['Page A!A3:Z','Page B!A3:Z','Page C!I2:M']);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    funct_b();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    funct_c();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    funct_c('A');
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    funct_d('B');
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    funct_e('A1','Page A','B1:I7');
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    funct_f('A1','Page B','B1:I7');
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    funct_g('Page A', 'A2:F', 2, 8);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    funct_h();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

What is the correct way for me to execute the functions only within the looping so that after each one of them, the worksheet is updated before moving on to the next step?

I tried to make the list but the functions are executed before the loop and I don't know how to proceed in these scenarios to reduce the cost of lines and better view the code.

```
  const functions = [
    funct_a(['Page A!A3:Z','Page B!A3:Z','Page C!I2:M']),
    funct_b(),
    funct_c(),
    funct_c('A'),
    funct_d('B'),
    funct_e('A1','Page A','B1:I7'),
    funct_f('A1','Page B','B1:I7'),
    funct_g('Page A', 'A2:F', 2, 8),
    funct_h()
  ];

  for (let i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {
    functions[i]();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
```

Comment: My goodness what kind of behemoth are you running! A couple things to note, `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` is automatically triggered, triggering it has never done anything for me in the past. You should try making your functions more efficient, or see if `Utilities.sleep(2000)` helps between functions.

Comment: Hard to answer a question  about a bunch of function I know nothing about aned are not defined in the provided code.

Comment: Unlike @NEWAZA I have seen many situations where SpreadsheetApp.flush() has made a huge difference.

Comment: Correction, flush is not automatically run, the rest still stands. In the past where I've felt I had to use flush it was generally due to inefficiencies in my code.

Comment: Hello Cooper, my question is actually how do I make it so that instead of the functions being executed when creating the list, they are executed in the looping. For example, I know that if there are no arguments, I could put ```funct_b``` in the list and inside the loop it would be ```functions[i]()```. But what about when there are arguments to pass, is there any way to do it?

Comment: Hi @NEWAZA in my case all ```SpreadsheetApp.flush()``` are necessary, one for each executed function, because I've had problems when I don't do it that way, so to be sure the spreadsheet is updated, I do it that way. I prefer spending more execution time than having problems with the final result.

Comment: I cannot understand the sitaution of `the functions are executed before the loop`. For example, can you provide your script of `funct_a`, `funct_b`, `funct_c`? If that cannot be understood from those scripts, I would like to confirm also other functions.

Comment: Hello @NEWAZA , I will do the tests today or tomorrow for understanding and execution, unfortunately I am not at home with my computer, but I will return as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this?

```
function a() {

  Logger.log(`A`)

}

function b(text) {

  Logger.log(`B ${text}`)
  
}

function c(text, text2) {

  Logger.log(`C ${text} ${text2}`)

}
```

.

```
function run() {

  [
    {
      Func: a,
      Args: [null]
    },
    {
      Func: b,
      Args: [`text`]
    },
    {
      Func: c,
      Args: [`text`, `text2`]
    }
  ].forEach(func => {

    func.Func(...func.Args)
    SpreadsheetApp.flush()

  })

}
```